# how to check and uncheck all checkbox in custom listview from activity?

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I trying to check and uncheck all checkboxes in my Activity by one click.
I tried this code :

```
private ListView mListView;
private Contacts_ListViewAdapter ContactViewAdapter;
private ArrayList<Contacts_ListView> ContactView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    intent = getIntent();
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Contacts_list);
    Selected_check_box = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Selected_check_box) ;
    View parentLayout = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
  Select_All.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private int ContactViewSize;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ListView lv = mListView ;
            int size = ContactViewAdapter.getCount();
            boolean check = lv.isItemChecked(0);
            for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
                lv.setItemChecked(i, !check);
    }
    });
```

It doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the information in your custom CursorAdapter because Listview only build enough "list view" for show and recycle reuse and dynamic change those views for efficiency.

Under your custom Adapter, add global variance and update it.

```
boolean allcheck = false; //Default unchecked
```

Update all checkbox at **bindView**

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
CheckBox box = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

      box.setChecked(allcheck);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

setItemChecked(position , value) - This is only valid if the choice mode has been set to CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE or CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE. Try setting it

```
listView.setChoiceMode(int mode)
```